# Load Data Into Popup

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

The idea is to show only the details of the corresponding challenge when a user clicks on the button view:
[image]

So far, I was only able to load all the `challenges` when I click on button `view`:
[image]

and that's understandable because in my `view-one-challenge.component.html`, I coded it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <div class="modal-header" >
    <h4 class="modal-title" >Challenge Details</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- HTML table for displaying a challenge details -->
        <table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>

            <tr *ngFor="let challenge of challenge_list">
                <td class="w-40-pct">Name</td>
                <td>{{challenge?.name}}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr *ngFor="let challenge of challenge_list">
                <td>Duration</td>
                <td>{{challenge?.duration}}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr *ngFor="let challenge of challenge_list">
                <td>Description</td>
                <td>{{challenge?.description}}</td>
            </tr>

            <tr *ngFor="let challenge of challenge_list">
                <td>Quiz</td>
                <td>{{challenge?.Quiz.title}}</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
    </div>
```

The `challenge_list` contains all the challenges that I'm getting from my REST API through `challengeService`, and here's how I fill it with data:

```
  ngOnInit() {
        console.log("inside ngOnInit...");
    this.challengeService.getChallenges().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.challenge_list = data;
      },
      error => {
        this.alertService.error(error);
      });
  }
```

The method that fetches the data from REST API is called `getChallenges()`, and gets the data through a HttpClient:

```
getChallenges(): Observable<Challenge[]> {
  console.log("inside getChallenges ===============");
    return this.http.get<Challenge[]>(this._challengeUrl);
}
```

What I would like to do is, instead of loading all the challenges every time I click on the button `view`, I would like to only display the data that corresponds to the `id`of the challenge being clicked on.

CLearly what I need is to create a method that takes an id:number as a parameter, loops through all the challenges and returns the one with the corresponding `id`. However, since I'm a little new to Angular, I don't know how to go about doing this. Any ideas or even hints would be immensely appreciated.

Also, I think I'm not loading the data in an elegant way because I'm using challengeService a second time to fetch the data from the REST API. Is there a way I could simply "copy" or "use" or "transfer" or "inject" the data that it's displayed in the first picture (and in another component) into my popup without having to call the API? Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass ID to your component, you get it in popup with Input, example

```
@Input() exampleId: number;
```

and you pass it like this:

```
<app-popup [exampleId]="theIdYouWantToPass"></app-popup>
```

Then just call the method and loop through everything inside:

```
forEach(const s of yourArray) {
  if(s.id == exampleId) {..}
}
```

hope it helps.

EDIT: you can pass any data like this, entire list so u dont have to call api

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is with a different HTML markup:
Iterate over challenge_list with ngFor and create each element separately:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <!-- HTML table for displaying a challenge details -->
    <table *ngIf="challenge_list != null" class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Duration</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Quiz</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let campaign of campaigns; let i = index">
                <td>{{challenge?.name}}</td>
                <td>{{challenge?.duration}}</td>
                <td>{{challenge?.description}}</td>
                <td>{{challenge?.Quiz.title}}</td>
                <td>
                    <!-- TODO: Add routerLink -->
                    <a (click)="viewDialog(challenge)">View</a>
                    <a (click)="openEdit(challenge)">View</a>
                    <a (click)="openDelete(challenge)">View</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

this way, every time a viewDialog() function will be called, you will have the entire challenge object as an input. Then you need to create a viewDialog() function in component that either shows the dialog or renders it anew.